# Why IDM(Internet Download Manager) can‘t download a .ts file with a direct address?

Tags: google-chrome, http, download

On the avgle.com（sorry it's a p**n website）, IDM(Internet Download Manager) can download the sniffed .ts file with chrome like this:
[image]. It does works!

However,when I copied the address of .ts file sniffed by IDM extension in Chrome, then put it to "Add URL" to download it, idm went to error with code 403？
[image]

In chrome->network, I could find the .ts file and "save as " it. 
At first I thought the difference between the two ways was "user-agent", I updated the version of idm to 6.35 and added a user-agent string, it doesn't work either.

So, 1)How can I download files with urls from the avgle.com?
    2)What the hell difference between the two ways to download?

the url is something like "http://xxxx.com/key=lagjlasjdgl=/media=hlsA/xxxx.mp4/seg-001.ts"

Answer (score 0):

finally,I found the reason。

There is a argument called 'referer' about the downloading link such as 'https://abc.video.com/key=abcabc,end=1583685322,limit=2/referer=force,.abcabc.com/data=1583685322/media=hlsA/1111.mp4/seg-1-v1-a1.ts'

The 'referer' argument is necessary for this site.

So the *.ef file should contain the referer "referer: https://abcabc.com"
or put the string 'https://abcabc.com' to the blank as below:
[image: Screenshot]